Find the recurrence relation to find the count of n-digit numbers such that no 3 consecutive digits are same
[I am a beginner in this topic, and this is the question I have been trying to solve, which is:
Let T(n) be the count of n-digit numbers (using digits 0, 1, . . . ,9, with first digit non-zero) such that no three consecutive digits are the same. Then which of the following is a correct recurrence relation for T(n)? Note that T(1) = 9 and T(2) = 90.
(A) T(n)=9T(n-1)+9T(n-2)
(B) T(n)=9T(n-1)+8T(n-2)+9
(C) T(n)=9T(n-1)+9
(D) T(n)=9T(n-1)-9T(n-2)
I tried it as, since its an n-digit number, the first position will have 9 places to choose from, excluding 0. The second position again will have 9 places to choose from, excluding the number we chose for the first digit place, and so on. So the answer I am getting at is 9T(n-1), which is obviously wrong.
I then tried the approach, where we look at the last digits of the number. Let A(n) denote the count of n digit numbers where last 2 digits are same, and B(n) denote the count where the last 2 digits are different. Let us look at A(n). If we fix the very last digit of the number, the second last digit gets fixed too(since we assumed the last 2 digits of the number are same. And they each get fixed in 10 ways(10 digits). Now, the third last digit gets fixed in 9 ways. So if we look at the number till its second last digit(excluding the digit at the nth position), we can say the n-1 digit number has the last 2 digits different, which we can also write as B(n-1), so A(n)=B(n-1)?]
Please help me. Any and all advice is appreciated. Thank you1

On your final paragraph, you are correct to say $A(n)=B(n-1)$ since there is one way of doubling a single final digit.
You can also say $B(n)=9(A(n-1)+B(n-1))$ since there are nine ways of introducing a new single final digit.
Since $T(n)=A(n)+B(n)$, this tells you $B(n)=9\,T(N-1)$ and so $A(n)=9\, T(n-2)$
and so $T(n)=9\,T(n-2)+9\,T(n-1)$, which is essentially answer (A).
The sequence is OEIS A057092 if you treat $0$ as a zero digit integer.

You can also say B(n)=9(A(n−1)+B(n−1))
since there are nine ways of introducing a new single final digit. Why will I need to introduce a new final digit when I have already fixed it?

@BakaKazuya All of your numbers counted in $A(n-1)$ and $B(n-1)$ end with a digit which you cannot reuse if you want an $n$-digit number ending in a single digit, but in each case you have $9$ other choices for the new single final digit

I am new at this and still learning, and am really struggling to understand what you said here:
You can also say B(n)=9(A(n−1)+B(n−1))
since there are nine ways of introducing a new single final digit.
Since T(n)=A(n)+B(n), this tells you B(n)=9T(N−1) and so A(n)=9T(n−2)

@BakaKazuya Try it with some actual numbers.  Clearly $A(1)=0$ and $B(1)=9$ and $T(1)=9$, while $A(2)=9$ and $B(2)=81$ and $T(2)=90$.  Can you see why $A(3)=81$ [take the $81$ examples counted in $B(2)$ and repeat their final digit] and $B(3)=810$ [take all the $9+81$ examples counted in $A(2)$ and $B(2)$ and put a new different final digit for the nine choices in each case] and  $T(3)=891$ [all the examples in $A(3)$ and $B(3)$]?

I understood everything here, except why is B1 = 9? Shouldn't it be 0 too? B1 means we are considering 1 digit numbers whose last two digits are different. Since its a one digit number, there is no question of two last digits, so it should be automatically 0, no?

@BakaKazuya I would say $B(1)$ is the number of $1$ digit numbers where the last two digits are not the same.  In this particular case, that is all nine of them $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ since we are treating $0$ as a zero-digit number.

I finally get it. Thank you so much for your time Henry
